# The smallest number divisible by $c$ given conditions on the remainders

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> $a,b,c$ are positive integers such that:
>
> (1) $a<2b$
>
> (2) the remainder on dividing $a$ by $b$ is $2r$; and
>
> (3) the remainder on dividing $a$ or $b$ by $c$ is $r$.
>
> Find the smallest  positive integer divisible by $c$ among the following >choices:
>
> i) $a+b\ $  ii) $\frac{a+b}2\ $  iii) $\frac{a+b}3\ $ iv) $2(a+b)\ $  v) $3(a+b)$

My work so far:

$$a+b\equiv 2r\pmod c \equiv bq+2r+b \pmod c \implies b(q+1)\equiv 0\pmod c$$
Also: $c|a-r,b-r\implies c|a-b$ which is not among the choices!

What shall we do?

Comment: I guess we should use $a<2b$ efficiently.Somehow we should find some quotients.

Comment: That's ok. Easy to do. I hope you won't mind if I correct the question ...

Comment: @almagest You're welcome,thank you.

Comment: Ok. I hope that is ok. I have deleted most of my comments. You might want to consider deleting some of yours. :) Oh, +1 for an interesting experience. I have learnt something!

Comment: Thank you almagest. $r$ could be zero,so I edited the question again to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the (now made clear) interpretation of "remainder", then
put all the conditions together
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le a = qb + 2r < 2b \hfill \cr 
  0 \le a = nc + r \hfill \cr 
  0 \le b = mc + r \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
do some re-arrangements
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  q = 1,\quad 2r < b \hfill \cr 
  b \le a = b + 2r < 2b \hfill \cr 
  b \le a = nc + r < 2b \hfill \cr 
  2r < b = nc - r \hfill \cr 
  b = mc + r \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
and it will be clear that
$$
{{a + b} \over 2} = nc
$$
is the minimal expression divisible by $c$

Comment: @almagest your punctualization is fully right: $a$ congruent $2r$ $mod(b)$ is not the same as telling that $2r$ is the remainder of $a/b$, which is the interpretation I took. So pls. read  my answer above under that assumption.

Comment: Your assumption was correct! Unfortunately, I cannot undo my downvote unless you make a trivial change (because they are locked after a certain amount of time has passed).

Comment: @almagest, ok, I made clear the assumption as it is now reported in edited post. In any case, thanks for pointing out the importance of expliciting the assumptions made (and of using the correct symbolism!)

Comment: Ok, now withdrawn downvote and indeed changed it to an upvote!